# Nuget a plugin mvvmcross, interface not registered

Tags: plugins, mvvmcross

I've got a plugin for mvvmcross using nuget.

When I try and use the plugin it tells me that an interface under the namespace of the plugin hasn't been registered.

Is there anything else after adding the plugin to my project via nuget that I need to add into my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#how-plugins-are-loaded).

Specifically:

> Each plugin load is normally initiated from a bootstrap class. These bootstrap classes are added in your UI projects and generally look something like:

```
public class ColorPluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Color.PluginLoader>
{
}
```